# Bat script for clear firefox cookies and cache

Tags: firefox, batch-file, cookies

I want to clear my Mozilla Firefox cookies when my browser is still running. I tried following code, but it is working only when browser is closed.

`@echo off
set DataDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
del /q /s /f "%DataDir%"
rd /s /q "%DataDir%"
for /d %%x in (C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*) do del /q /s /f %%x\*sqlite`

Is there any way to clear cookies when browser is running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fire fox is using the files that you are trying to remove so it will not allow you to remove them. the only way is to close the browser. You could use this to close firefox.

```
taskkill /im "firefox.exe"
```

So it would be like:

```
@echo off
taskkill /im "firefox.exe"
set DataDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
del /q /s /f "%DataDir%"
rd /s /q "%DataDir%"
for /d %%x in (C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*) do del /q /s /f %%x\*sqlite
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You are right, Firefox would not allow removal of in-use files but see I have used /f option for forcefully remove them.

Comment: @PrashantShukla Even with this it wont work. Say if Firefox is a three leg chair. If you take a leg of then it will fall down. So even if it was possible to remove them with out closing Firefox it is likely to crash (fall down).

Comment: When we delete firefox cookies manually by using "option>privacy>use custom setting for history" they get deleted even  they dont require any browser restart. How firefox does it?

Comment: To know this i would need Firefox's source code. And Firefox has full control over its self batch doesn't have full control over Firefox so the only way for cmd to do it is to taskkill it.

Comment: The previous script link from Rafiqul Islam, potential malware with warnings, security risk. And has been there for 5 years. Did anyone try it?